# What does this red square icon mean in Visual Studio 2013 Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, ankhsvn

In the image below, there are red square icons next to items in the Solution Explorer.  I can't figure out what they indicate.  I'm using Resharper and AnkhSVN, so they may be from either of those two packages, or from Visual Studio itself.  Does anyone have any idea what they mean?

[image: an image of solution explorer showing red squares next to some items]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely from Subversion, saying that you have changes in the file

Comment: It's AnkhSVN, I guess.

Comment: Yes, it is AnkhSVN.  Based on your answer, I looked up the icon legend for AnkhSVN and saw that the red square does indicate that the file has been modified.  Thank you!